# Multiple JS errors in Chrome on line 1, but no errors in Edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I have to use some outdated scripts and bumped into multiple JS errors in Chrome. All JS scripts on page give exactly same error in Chrome - "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token" on line 1.
Absolutely same code works fine in Edge.

I tried all I can imagine - reload, shuffle, rename, unminimized still the same.
Any ideas on what could cause that would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Without the code there is nothing we can suggest, are you sure it is really javascript which is being returned and not some kind of server error? I honestly don't get how your post got up-voted, as it is offtopic

Comment: @Icepickle not sure why are you talking on behalf of all, but anyway ... shouldn't server error also produce error in Edge? What kind of the server error could create error only in Chrome and not in Edge?

Comment: But it is offtopic, no matter how you look at it. Read your own question and tell me based on what it would make it possible to give you a viable answer? The only thing would be guesses, there is a close reason exactly for this, nl why isn't this code working (without supplying the code itself). It could have been a network error, the fact is, we cannot not tell based on the given data

Comment: @Icepickle I still don't understand why are you talking on behalf of all. It's absolutely clear, that I don't expect guesses, but the first hand experience. If you don't have such experience, then you should skip the question. Your flood doesn't help for sure.

Comment: I would be very surprised a genuine answer is coming based on the data given ;)

Comment: @Icepickle is correct, there isn't much anyone can do with this little info. It would help if you were to copy the HTML into the question. I would also suggest taking a screenshot of the Network tab in the browser dev tools. And then copying *the entire response* from the shortest script as well. It's possibly some encoding or mime-type thing that Chome isn't happy with, but we can't really help much if we can't see exactly what is causing the error.

Comment: Could be the JS files are being served with the incorrect MIME type. I've found Chrome does a more thorough job rejecting those than Edge does. No way to say definitively though, as the others have noted -- that's just my best guess.

Comment: For ex., this is the first file respond.min.js unminimized: https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond/blob/master/src/respond.js   I tried to use it this way and the errors in Chrome were the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with files encoding. It was ANSI.
Everything works fine when I changed to UTF-8.
Obviously Edge is not so strict on this matter as Chrome.